# Jquery .replace unknown vale in ()

Tags: jquery, opencart

I'm trying to make an open cart theme and want to remove the category product count searching i can only find an option to change the core (don't want to do this as i wish to distribute the theme)

do i thought i might try remove with Jquery it generates

```
<li><a href="http://www.site.com/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=25_28">Monitors (2)</a></li>
```

i want to remove or add span around the () not shire how as the value in-between is dynamic
(an opencart theme solution would also work)

hope this makes sense

thanks in advance

Mitchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value in the brackets is numeric (and assuming the preceding text doesn't include brackets), you could do:

```
$('li a').each(function() {
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/\(([0-9]+)\)/, "<span>($1)</span>");
    $(this).html(replaced); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpYMW/1/

This adds a span around the parentheses. I made the span bold in the example so you can see the effect more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a").each(function(){
   var text = $(this).html();
   text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("(") -1);
   $(this).html(text);
});
```